# submit multiple forms with single submit button in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have 1 php page containing 2 forms and 1 submit button.i want to submit both forms with this single button.My code works perfectly but there is 1 problem that in each form only 1 field submitted successfully. Below is my html and javascript code, plz tell me where i have error

2 html forms

```
<form name="form">
      <input type="text" name="a" value="a">
      <input type="text" name="b" value="b">
</form>
<form name="form">
      <input type="text" name="c" value="c">
      <input type="text" name="d" value="d">
</form>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button" value="Submit" onClick="submitAllDocumentForms()">
```

Javascript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/* Collect all forms in document to one and post it */
function submitAllDocumentForms() {
var arrDocForms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
var formCollector = document.createElement("form");
with(formCollector)
{
method = "post";
action = "test.php";
name = "formCollector";
id = "formCollector";
}
for(var ix=0;ix<arrDocForms.length;ix++) {
appendFormVals2Form(arrDocForms[ix], formCollector);
}
document.body.appendChild(formCollector);
formCollector.submit();

}
/* Function: add all elements from ``frmCollectFrom´´ and append them to ``frmCollector´´ before returning ``frmCollector´´*/
function appendFormVals2Form(frmCollectFrom, frmCollector) {
var frm = frmCollectFrom.elements;
for(var ix = 0 ; ix < frm.length ; ix++)
frmCollector.appendChild(frm[ix]);
return frmCollector;
}
</script>
```

My php code to echo submitted values

```
<?php
echo $_POST['a'];
echo $_POST['b'];
echo $_POST['c'];
echo $_POST['d'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `appendChild()` takes the element away from the form, modifying the `elements` array as well as its length. To avoid this, you can e.g. store the number of elements in a variable and process the array of elements starting from the last element:

```
var frm = frmCollectFrom.elements; 
var nElems = frm.length;
for(var ix = nElems - 1; ix >= 0 ; ix--)
  frmCollector.appendChild(frm[ix]);
```